# Question on orthogonal functions for Fourier series

Tags: fourier-transform

so we say that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx) \cos( mx) dx = \frac{1}{2} [\frac{sin((n+m)x)}{n+m}+ \frac{sin((n-m)x)}{n-m}]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0  $$ for $n\not=m$

but if $n =m$ then $$\frac{1}{2} [0+ \frac{sin(2mx)}{n-m}]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0$$
$$\frac{2\sin(2m\pi)}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$$

why does one have to assert $n = m$ before integration to avoid this?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The middle equation on the top with the $n-m$ in the denominator is not correct at least when $n=m$. Clearly, for $n=m$ the result is positive (and finite) since $\int \cos^2(nx)dx$ is the integral of a manifestly non-negative (and finite) quantity (a square of a number less than or equal to 1) over a finite interval.  In fact, it is well known that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^2(nx) dx = \pi$, for any integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: wrong sign, you wrote $2m$ while it was $n-m=0$ in the next to last line.

You skipped a step. Before computing the integral, if $n=m$:
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{1}{2}\bigl(\cos(2n x)+\cos(0)\bigr)dx$$
The term containing $n-m$ is a constant, so you can't integrate it into a sine function.

It's like when you want to integrate $x^n$, you have to separate the case $n=-1$ *before* you do the computation, because otherwise you'll step outside the validity domain of a formula.

Edit: another way to view this is to use $\varepsilon=n-m$ and run the computation with $\varepsilon\neq 0$. At the end, do a Taylor expansion of the problematic term to get the correct result.